# Trimming part of a returned field

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query on two tables.

```
    SELECT vcc.name AS item, vcc.prodid, vcc.quantity AS qty, UPPER( vcc.custom_message ) AS nickname, vfd1.value AS fullname, vfd2.value AS email, vcc.purchaseid, vcc.price, (
vcc.quantity * vcc.price
) AS sub
FROM vxu_4_wpsc_cart_contents AS vcc
INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd1 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd1.log_id
AND vfd1.form_id =2
INNER JOIN vxu_4_wpsc_submited_form_data AS vfd2 ON vcc.purchaseid = vfd2.log_id
AND vfd2.form_id =9
```

Which returns this (image attached)[image: result]

Is it even possible to TRIM the 'size' detail (ie Small/Medium/XL etc) from the Item column, so that that potentially sensitive info is not displayed?

The php I'm using to display the query is this:

```
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
          echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->fullname .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->nickname .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->item .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->qty .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->email .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->price .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->sub .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->purchaseid .'</td>';
          echo '<td>' . $print->prodid .'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Not really `trim`, but use some regexp or find symbols positions to find a substring.

Comment: Do you want to display (for example) Demo Hoodies (Small) instead of Demo Hoodies (Small, Kelly Green) ?

Comment: Hi - instead display Demo Hoodies (Kelly Green) - omitting the (Small)

Comment: Why are product sizes "sensitive information"? It's no secret that we're getting fatter these days. :)

Comment: The plan is to publish limited sales logs on the site being developed, so that others can see who orders what. But I fear that publishing someone's 'size' may be off putting for some people. Hence the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove that from the `item` column before printing it:

```
$item = preg_replace('/\b(?:Small|Medium|Large|XL|XXL)\b,? */', '', $print->item); // remove size
$item = str_replace(' ()', '', $item); // If there's nothing else in the parentheses, remove it entirely
echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
```

Comment: You guys are just so clever - it worked first time out! Will of course 'accept' your answer.  Again, thanks

Comment: Really, really picky question - if a field only has size details eg. Demo Polo shirts in the table I posted, the print is (). Can the code be tweaked to stop that?

Comment: That's trivially removed with `str_replace` after the first replacement.

Comment: Thank you! - much, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have control over the schema, but it seems to me that combining the size and item name is a denormalization, since size (as well as colour) is an attribute of the item, just as its name is.

So if I had control of the schema, I would split the size (and colour) out into separate columns. Then, it would be trivial to not include the size.

UPDATing the new columns could be done with Barmar's excellent preg_replace() suggestion.

Another alternative would be to use the MySQL fork, [MariaDB 10](https://mariadb.com/resources/downloads), which has [VIRTUAL columns](https://mariadb.com/blog/putting-virtual-columns-good-use). Then, you could define a new column whose value is derived from other columns, such as using MySQL string functions to extract just the name info.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your thoughts on this. I don't really have (practical) control over the schema - it's a Wordpress plugin!